# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php, web

Problem with in_array() on a php code. I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 15
    [4] => 16
    [5] => 17
    [6] => 18
    [7] => 19
    [8] => 20
    [9] => 21
    [10] => 22
    [11] => 23
    [12] => 24
    [13] => 25
    [14] => 26
    [15] => 27
    [16] => 28
    [17] => 29
)
```

And the following function removes an element from the array (since unset does not keep the indexes):

```
function removeFromArray($value, $array) {
    // If value is in the array
    if (in_array($value, $array)) {
        // Get the key of the value
        $key = array_search($value, $array);
        // Remove the element
        unset($array[$key]);
        // Fix the key indexes
        $array = array_values($array);
        return $array;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the error: "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given" when I do the in_array($value, $array), if condition. This happens for whatever element of the array.

I've made a check with is_array() on the $array variable and it returns true, so the variable is recognized as an array. Any thoughts?

Edit:

I define the array as follows:

```
$array = array(11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29);
```

And call the function this way: (for example: if I want to remove number 11)

```
$array= removeFromArray(11, $array);
```

Comment: Please show us how  you are calling the function and the array declaration.

Comment: Added the function call and array definition at the end.

Comment: Using reserved keywords as variables is a major programming faux pas.

Comment: I tried your code, and got no error

Comment: In your function, as the first line, add: `var_dump($array)`. I'm going to guess that it is empty.

Comment: I'm using the name "array" for this example only, I can not share the real name of the variables due to the fact that the program is company protected.

Comment: Then you probably have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Solved, the problem was in a different code piece. Sorry for wasting everyone's time, and thanks for all the help and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.  This is not an answer, it's just to show that your code is fine.

I just tested this as follows:

```
<?php
function removeFromArray($value, $array) {
    // If value is in the array
    if (in_array($value, $array)) {
        // Get the key of the value
        $key = array_search($value, $array);
        // Remove the element
        unset($array[$key]);
        // Fix the key indexes
        $array = array_values($array);
        return $array;
    }
    return false;
}

$array = array(11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29);
$array= removeFromArray(11, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

The result:

```
[vinod@wiplnx01:/home/workspace/php/playground]$ php array_test.php 
array(17) {
  [0] =>
  int(13)
  [1] =>
  int(14)
  [2] =>
  int(15)
  [3] =>
  int(16)
  [4] =>
  int(17)
  [5] =>
  int(18)
  [6] =>
  int(19)
  [7] =>
  int(20)
  [8] =>
  int(21)
  [9] =>
  int(22)
  [10] =>
  int(23)
  [11] =>
  int(24)
  [12] =>
  int(25)
  [13] =>
  int(26)
  [14] =>
  int(27)
  [15] =>
  int(28)
  [16] =>
  int(29)
}
```

And the PHP version, although this should not matter:

```
[vinod@wiplnx01:/home/workspace/php/playground]$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun  6 2013 09:20:50) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

So please check if you have typos or something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In calling of removeFromArray($value, $array), if $array is not array then 'in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array' error appears.